# CodeIgniter - Join Two Tables for Output by Day in JS Graphing Trouble

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

Having trouble with one of my join statements to get an output by day in CI for a JS line chart. Have researched heavily here, but can't seem to get anything to work.

Here's what I have in my model

```
function get_all ( $start_date, $end_date)
{
    $ret = array();

    $this->db->select('DATE(created_at) AS DAY,  COUNT(*) AS COUNT');
    $this->db->from('table1'); 
    $this->db->where('item_id =', 5);
    $this->db->where('created_at >=', $start_date);
    $this->db->where('created_at <=', $end_date);
    $this->db->join('table2', 'table2.id = table1.part_id AND table2.stock_id = 1', 'left' );
    $this->db->group_by('DAY(created_at)');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $ret[$row->DAY] = intval($row->COUNT);
    }

    return $ret;

}
```

Can comment out the join, and it works fine. I've tried several different modifications to it, but no matter which way I attempt, the data doesn't get loaded.

Any insight greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this is resolved, I have it working anyway... for anyone who runs into a similar issue:

```
function get_all ( $start_date, $end_date)
{
    $ret = array();

    $this->db->select('DATE(table2.created_at) AS DAY,  COUNT(*) AS COUNT');
    $this->db->from('table1');
    $this->db->join('table2', 'table2.part_id = table1.id AND table2.created_at >= \'' . $start_date . '\' AND table2.created_at <= \'' . $end_date . '\' AND table2.item_id = 5', 'left');
    $this->db->where('table1.stock_id =',  1);
    $this->db->group_by('DAY(table2.created_at)');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $ret[$row->DAY] = intval($row->COUNT);
    }

    return $ret;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Not tested.

```
function get_all ( $start_date, $end_date)
    {
        $ret = array();

        $this->db->select('table1.DATE(created_at) AS DAY,  COUNT(*) AS COUNT');
        $this->db->from('table1');
        $this->db->join('table2', 'table2.id = table1.part_id', 'left');
        $this->db->where('table1.item_id =', 5);
        $this->db->where('table1.created_at >=', $start_date);
        $this->db->where('table1.created_at <=', $end_date);
        $this->db->where('table2.stock_id =',  1);
        $this->db->group_by('table1.DAY(created_at)');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $ret[$row->DAY] = intval($row->COUNT);
        }

        return $ret;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Gave this a try but still no data. What I've just noticed is that a similar join on graphs that don't require the count by day work fine. Possibly something to do with that?

Comment: Try to use count_all function from active records, maybe this will help you. $this->db->count_all_results();